# Implementing IRibbonExtensibility_GetCustomUI from VBA

Tags: vba, ribbon, outlook-2010

I've been trying to manipulate Outlook Ribbon, namely QAT icons, from VBA editor.
Found references to IRibbonExtensibility, which is actually recognized in class modules:

```
Implements IRibbonExtensibility

Public Function IRibbonExtensibility_GetCustomUI(ByVal RibbonID As String) As String
    'Must return XML
End Function
```

However, I can't get this interface instantiated:

Adding this code in `ThisOutlookSession` cause Outlook startup error.

Instantiating class modules with this code render IRibbonExtensability member as Nothing.

Is this only available for COM Addins? Any other direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in case of Outlook the Fluent UI customizations are available through COM add-ins only.

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v=office.12)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)